# How to debug a C++ program using arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class XIIB
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int roll;
    float marks;

public:
    void getdata(char a[30],int i,int j,float k)
    {
        name[30]=a[30];
        age=i;
        roll=j;
        marks=k;
    }
    void putdata(void)
    {   
        cout<<"Name:"<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"Age:"<<age<<endl;
        cout<<"Roll:"<<roll<<endl;
        cout<<"Marks:"<<marks<<endl;
    }
};
const int size=5;
XIIB student[size];
void main()
{
    char x[30];
    int ag;
    int rno;
    float mrks;
    for(int p=0;p<size;p++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Name,Age,Roll and Marks of Student"<<p+1<<endl;
        cin>>x>>ag>>rno>>mrks;
        student[p].getdata(x,ag,rno,mrks);
    }
    for(p=0;p<size;p++)
    {
        cout<<"Student"<<p+1<<endl;
        student[p].putdata();
    }
    getch();
}
```

This program compiles without any error. Also takes the input for Name, Roll No, Age and Marks as expected but it is unable to display the name of the Students. I seem to have made some error in the getdata or putdata functions.

Comment: `name[30]=a[30];` thats undefined behaviour, all the rest of the code is kind of irrelevant, because it blows up in the first line. An `array[30]` has 30 elements and its last one is `array[29]`

Comment: It's 2016 not 1996, stop using `<iostream.h>`

Comment: @JonathanWakely sorry but i am using old compiler .Yes i am confused in the array portion

Comment: even if it was 1916, this code has terrible (ie. almost nonexisting) formatting.

Comment: try `name=a` instead

Comment: Since you are using c++, instead of character array, you can use `std::string` for the name.

Comment: @niceman That will not compile. `name` evaluates to the address of that array which is not an lvalue.

Comment: @bkVnet hmm then using `std::string` is the right choice, otherwise he must use `std::strcpy`

Comment: @niceman yes it'll probably be best, but the other option as you said is `strcpy`. BTW its not part of the `std` namespace.

Comment: @bkVnet it *is* in the `std` namespace, along with all of C++'s port of the C standard library. Implementations are allowed, but not required, to provide equivalents in the global namespace.

Comment: @Quentin Good to know. I never used it like that because i suppose my implementation provide a global equivalent.

Comment: Guys it worked now as expected by replacing name[30]=a[30] by strcpy(name,a); as directed in the answers.I made a mistake in copying character array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `void getdata(char a[30],int i,int j,float k)`: `name[30]=a[30];` does not make what you expect and is undefined behavior; (this copies the 31st character of `a` to the 31st character of `name`, while both strings are only 30 characters long.)

You have to replace `name[30]=a[30];` by `strcpy(name,a);` and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

your getdata has a problem, character arrays cannot be copied like that, try this

```
void getdata(char a[30],int i,int j,float k)
{
    strcpy(name,a); //change this line
    age=i;
    roll=j;
    marks=k;
}
```

instead of

```
name[30]=a[30];
```